# Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 16 RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am getting below error in driver when running a spark yarn application on spark-1.6.2 cluster:

```
2017-03-27 18:41:50 SIGTERM handler [INFO ] ApplicationMaster - Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 16
2017-03-27 18:41:50 SIGTERM handler [ERROR] ApplicationMaster - RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
2017-03-27 18:41:50 Driver [ERROR] SparkDriver - Failed to start the driver for TestApp
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2014)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2048)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.ContextWaiter.waitForStopOrError(ContextWaiter.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.awaitTermination(StreamingContext.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.awaitTermination(JavaStreamingContext.scala:632)
    at com.test.example.SparkDriver.submit(SparkDriver.java:119)
    at com.test.example.SparkDriver.main(SparkDriver.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was coming on `HDP(hortonworks) Cluster` and it was `HDP upgrade` issue. The upgrade for the HDP environment was in between and upgrade was paused on this HDP Cluster. Once the upgrade got finalized the issue got fixed and I was able to run the `spark yarn applications` on the cluster.